# Cast a String object to XMLNode object

Tags: java, xml

I have a **String** which has XML data as a String. I would like to assign this data to a **XMLNode** object. Can you please suggest how I do this.

```
String xmlData = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <EMPDETAILSREPORTVO> <P_PERSON_ID>11</P_PERSON_ID> <LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> <EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> <EENAME>Camille Heiden</EENAME> <EMPLOYEENUMBER>10</EMPLOYEENUMBER> <JOBNAME>CON600.Consultant</JOBNAME> <SUPNAME>Sharon Colby</SUPNAME> <PROPOSEDSALARYN>3617.98</PROPOSEDSALARYN> <DATEPRINTED>2013-10-29T11:53:02.000+03:00</DATEPRINTED> </EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> </LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> </EMPDETAILSREPORTVO>";

XMLNode xmlNode = ???
```

would like to set the string to the XMLNode object

BM

Comment: post your sample code(especially String having xml data)

Comment: please provide your codes

Comment: String xmlData = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <EMPDETAILSREPORTVO> <P_PERSON_ID>11</P_PERSON_ID> <LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> <EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> <EENAME>Camille Heiden</EENAME> <EMPLOYEENUMBER>10</EMPLOYEENUMBER> <JOBNAME>CON600.Consultant</JOBNAME> <SUPNAME>Sharon Colby</SUPNAME> <PROPOSEDSALARYN>3617.98</PROPOSEDSALARYN> <DATEPRINTED>2013-10-29T11:53:02.000+03:00</DATEPRINTED> </EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> </LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> </EMPDETAILSREPORTVO>";  


XMLNode xmlNode = ??? (would like to set the string to the XMLNode object)

Comment: Type full qualified name of class XMLNode

Comment: `oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLNode xmlNode = ??` (would like to set the string to the XMLNode object)

Comment: Any update on the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB for this task, check the example bellow,

```
//EMPDETAILSREPORTVO POJO

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "EMPDETAILSREPORTVO")
class EMPDETAILSREPORTVO{
    private int P_PERSON_ID;

    @XmlElement(name = "LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW", type = LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW.class)
    List<LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> list = new ArrayList<LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW>();

    public EMPDETAILSREPORTVO() {   
    }

    public EMPDETAILSREPORTVO(List<EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setEMPDETAILSREPORTVOList(List<EMPDETAILSREPORTVO> eList){
        this.list = eList;
    }

    //other getters and setters ...
}

//EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW POJO

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW")
class EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW{
    private String EENAME;
    private int EMPLOYEENUMBER;
    private String JOBNAME;
    private String SUPNAME;
    private double PROPOSEDSALARYN;
    private Date DATEPRINTED;

    //getters and setters...
}

public static void main(String [] args){
EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW obj_1 = new EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW();
    obj_1.setEENAME("Name");
    obj_1.setEMPLOYEENUMBER(110);
    obj_1.setJOBNAME("Job Name");
    obj_1.setSUPNAME("Supervisor Name");
    obj_1.setPROPOSEDSALARYN(5000.00);
    obj_1.setDATEPRINTED(new Date());

    List<EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> list = new ArrayList<EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW>();
    list.add(obj_1);    

    EMPDETAILSREPORTVO eMPDETAILSREPORTVO = new EMPDETAILSREPORTVO(list);
    eMPDETAILSREPORTVO.setEMPDETAILSREPORTVOList(list);
    eMPDETAILSREPORTVO.setP_PERSON_ID(10);

    marshalUser(eMPDETAILSREPORTVO);    

}



//test 

public static void marshal(EMPDETAILSREPORTVO object)
            throws IOException, JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context;
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Object.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        m.marshal(object, stringWriter);
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
        stringWriter.close();
}


public static void unMarshal(String xmlString)
            throws IOException, JAXBException {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(EMPDETAILSREPORTVO.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);

            EMPDETAILSREPORTVO eMPDETAILSREPORTVO = (EMPDETAILSREPORTVO) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: `String xmlData = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <EMPDETAILSREPORTVO> <P_PERSON_ID>11</P_PERSON_ID> <LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> <EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> <EENAME>Camille Heiden</EENAME> <EMPLOYEENUMBER>10</EMPLOYEENUMBER> <JOBNAME>CON600.Consultant</JOBNAME> <SUPNAME>Sharon Colby</SUPNAME> <PROPOSEDSALARYN>3617.98</PROPOSEDSALARYN> <DATEPRINTED>2013-10-29T11:53:02.000+03:00</DATEPRINTED> </EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> </LIST_EMPDETAILSREPORTVOROW> </EMPDETAILSREPORTVO>"; XMLNode xmlNode = ???`

Comment: Would like to have the my code to work in such a way. So that I can assign my XMLNode object. I don't see you using XMLNode class.  Should be like `oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLNode xmlNode = ??`